# An SQL Statement to sort within a query

Tags: mysql

I want to develop code that will allow a subset within a query. I have three fields "batchid", "month" and "year". Each batch may have several months and more than one year. The final order I need is the highest month year combination.

The following table I hope illustrates this.

```
Batch  Month  Year
5      12     2013
        1     2014
6      11     2013 
        3     2014
4       1     2014
        2     2014
```

The required order is

```
Batch  Month  Year
5      12     2013
        1     2014
4       1     2014
        2     2014
6      11     2013
        3     2014
```

You can see each batch is sorted to the latest date in the batch and each batch is ordered to the latest date in the batch.
I have got it as far as the year is concerned but cannot figure out the month.
The first statement determines the lowest and highest dates.

I am new to this forum and for that matter not experienced using VBA and have not beanpole to get the SQL statement into this post so I apologize na hope this may make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.batch, t1.month, t1.year  
FROM tmp t1 
JOIN 
(SELECT batch, max(year*12+month) mord FROM tmp GROUP BY batch ORDER BY mord) t2 
ON t2.batch = t1.batch 
ORDER BY t2.mord, t1.year, t1.month
```

yields

```
+-------+-------+------+
| batch | month | year |
+-------+-------+------+
|     5 |    12 | 2013 |
|     5 |     1 | 2014 |
|     4 |     1 | 2014 |
|     4 |     2 | 2014 |
|     6 |    11 | 2013 |
|     6 |     3 | 2014 |
+-------+-------+------+
```